# How to check all items match in an array using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to have a function in javascript (jQuery if possible) that will allow me to pass an array of ids into a function, and check if each value is found in another array to return TRUE.

e.g

```
var ids1 = [1, 6, 9, 11, 20];
var ids2 = [5, 6, 9, 11];

function check_array(ids)
{
    var search = [1, 6, 9, 11, 20];
    // do some checking here

    // if all ids are matched up return TRUE; 

    // otherwise return FALSE;
}
```

In this instance - the first var ids1 would return TRUE, while the second var ids2 would return FALSE.

Can anyone suggest the simplest/cleanest method for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I didn't try myself purely as I thought that they might be a javascript function that already does this that I am not aware e.g. array_diff() in PHP would allow me to do this, I wondered if javascript had a similar function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function check_array(ids1, ids2) {
    return $(ids1).not(ids2).get().length === 0;
}

var ids1 = [1, 6, 9, 11, 20];
var ids2 = [5, 6, 9, 11];
console.log(check_array(ids1, ids2)); // false
console.log(check_array(ids2, ids1)); // false
var search = [1, 6, 9, 11, 20];
console.log(check_array(search, ids2)); // false
console.log(check_array(search, ids1)); // true
```

Although the generic version above is enough, here's one that's exactly what you ask:

```
function check_array(ids) {
    var search = [1, 6, 9, 11, 20];
    return $(search).not(ids).get().length === 0;
}
var ids1 = [1, 6, 9, 11, 20];
var ids2 = [5, 6, 9, 11];
console.log(check_array(ids1)); // true
console.log(check_array(ids2)); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have numeric IDs, then this is possibly the simplest way.

[`1,2,3].toString() === [1,2,3].toString()  //=> true`

If you want to determine if all the IDs in array A exist in array B (but array B may have others), try [[].every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: arg got me to it... Please add sorting just before comparing :)

Comment: great stuff either of them should work :)

Comment: what if search array has more value than ids? Op wants to return true or false?

Comment: @roasted - it depends if that's what the OP wants. If so, they can try `every` as suggested in the edit.

Comment: @Graham ya, i'm agree with you, we don't know what OP wants as his question is quite incomplete

Comment: cheers guys - some good ideas there.